# Perl: read the contents between double quotes in a string

Tags: perl

I have a string and some content of string is in double quotes.
For example:

```
test_case_be "+test+tx+rx+path"
```

For the above input I want to split the entire strings into two parts:

1. The string outside the double quotes [`test_case_be`] I want to store in `$temp1`.
2. The string inside the double quotes  [`+test+tx+rx+path`] I want to store this in `$temp2`.

Can someone help me with a sample code on how to do the above?

Answer (score 2):

This can do it:

```
my $input_string = qq(test_case_be "+test+tx+rx+path");
my $re = qr/^([^"]+)"([^"]+)"/;

# Evaluating in list context this way affects the first variable to the
# first group and so on
my ($before, $after) = ($input_string =~ $re);

print <<EOF;
before: $before
after: $after
EOF
```

Output:

```
before: test_case_be 
after: +test+tx+rx+path
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str ~= /(.*)\"(.*)\"/; //capture group before quotes and between quotes
$temp1 = $1; // assign first group to temp1
$temp2 = $2; // 2nd group to temp2
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
my $str='test_case_be "+test+tx+rx+path"';
my ($temp1,$temp2)=split(/"/,$str);
```

Comment: downvoter: Please mention the reason for downvoting so that I can know my mistake.

Comment: The likely reason for the downvote is that it is not using a regex.  I'm not sure that warrants it; this is Perl so TMTOWTDI (there's more than one way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'test_case_be "+test+tx+rx+path"';
my ( $temp1, $temp2 ) = $string =~ /([^\s"]+)/g;

print "\$temp1: $temp1\n\$temp2: $temp2";
```

Output:

```
$temp1: test_case_be
$temp2: +test+tx+rx+path
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str =~ /"(.*?)"/;
$inside_quotes = $1;
$outside_quotes = $`.$';
```

Comment: Generally, it is not a good idea to use ``$` `` or `$'`; they apply a tax (cost) to all regular expressions in the program.  In isolation, they aren't too awful, so for a simple case like this, it can be used.  But you should definitely avoid using them if the code is going to become a module.  Your answer would be fine if you pointed this out; leaving it without that information is not doing other people a great service.